# How can I prevent React NOT to redownload an image with same url?

Tags: reactjs

Suppose I have such could which may generate several img elements on my page:

```
const defaultImages = ['A', 'B'];

class App extends React.Component {
state = {
    images: [],
}

componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
    // I'd like to make react force rebuild the img elements
    this.setState({images: []});
    this.setState({images: defaultImages});
    }, 50);
}

render() {
    return (
    this.state.images.map((value)=> {
        // Everytime when a new img element is created a new http request to the url will be made. 
        // Can I make React to reuse the already downloaded image, with same url, instead of redownload it again?
        return <img key={value} src={`Images/${value}.png`}/>;
    })
    );
}
```

The content of my real image list might be changed on condition, such as add or remove some, but the urls would be in a the same set. However, when the image list was rebuilt all the urls will be redonwload thus the img elements get `blink` which I want to avoid.

Comment: Never mind. I found the reason of the blinking is I always opened the `Developer tool` with option `Disable cache` checked.